# Coverview widget in .xml (android)

Tags: android, coverflow

Coverview is a widget ive implemented from http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/02/android-coverflow-widget-v2.html and it works until i want to use it .xml instead to add buttons and stuff. I have no idea how to link the two and any help would be really appreciated

My main activity:

```
package cover.flow.test;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.LinearGradient;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode;
import android.graphics.Shader.TileMode;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType;

 public class CoverFlowExampleActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 CoverFlow coverFlow;
 coverFlow = new CoverFlow(this);

 coverFlow.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

 ImageAdapter coverImageAdapter =  new ImageAdapter(this);

 //coverImageAdapter.createReflectedImages();

 coverFlow.setAdapter(coverImageAdapter);

 coverFlow.setSpacing(-25);
 coverFlow.setSelection(4, true);
 coverFlow.setAnimationDuration(1000);


 setContentView(coverFlow);

}

 public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
 int mGalleryItemBackground;
 private Context mContext;

 private FileInputStream fis;

 private Integer[] mImageIds = {
   R.drawable.kasabian_kasabian,
         R.drawable.starssailor_silence_is_easy,
         R.drawable.killers_day_and_age,
         R.drawable.garbage_bleed_like_me,
         R.drawable.death_cub_for_cutie_the_photo_album,
         R.drawable.kasabian_kasabian,
         R.drawable.massive_attack_collected,
         R.drawable.muse_the_resistance,
         R.drawable.starssailor_silence_is_easy
 };

 private ImageView[] mImages;

 public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
  mContext = c;
  mImages = new ImageView[mImageIds.length];
 }
  public boolean createReflectedImages() {
      //The gap we want between the reflection and the original image
      final int reflectionGap = 4;


      int index = 0;
      for (int imageId : mImageIds) {
    Bitmap originalImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), 
      imageId);
       int width = originalImage.getWidth();
       int height = originalImage.getHeight();


       //This will not scale but will flip on the Y axis
       Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
       matrix.preScale(1, -1);

       //Create a Bitmap with the flip matrix applied to it.
       //We only want the bottom half of the image
       Bitmap reflectionImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalImage, 0, height/2, width, height/2, matrix, false);


       //Create a new bitmap with same width but taller to fit reflection
       Bitmap bitmapWithReflection = Bitmap.createBitmap(width 
         , (height + height/2), Config.ARGB_8888);

      //Create a new Canvas with the bitmap that's big enough for
      //the image plus gap plus reflection
      Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmapWithReflection);
      //Draw in the original image
      canvas.drawBitmap(originalImage, 0, 0, null);
      //Draw in the gap
      Paint deafaultPaint = new Paint();
      canvas.drawRect(0, height, width, height + reflectionGap, deafaultPaint);
      //Draw in the reflection
      canvas.drawBitmap(reflectionImage,0, height + reflectionGap, null);

      //Create a shader that is a linear gradient that covers the reflection
      Paint paint = new Paint(); 
      LinearGradient shader = new LinearGradient(0, originalImage.getHeight(), 0, 
        bitmapWithReflection.getHeight() + reflectionGap, 0x70ffffff, 0x00ffffff, 
        TileMode.CLAMP); 
      //Set the paint to use this shader (linear gradient)
      paint.setShader(shader); 
      //Set the Transfer mode to be porter duff and destination in
      paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.DST_IN)); 
      //Draw a rectangle using the paint with our linear gradient
      canvas.drawRect(0, height, width, 
        bitmapWithReflection.getHeight() + reflectionGap, paint); 

      ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
      imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapWithReflection);
      imageView.setLayoutParams(new CoverFlow.LayoutParams(120, 180));
      imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
      mImages[index++] = imageView;

      }
   return true;
}

 public int getCount() {
     return mImageIds.length;
 }

 public Object getItem(int position) {
     return position;
 }

 public long getItemId(int position) {
     return position;
 }

 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  //Use this code if you want to load from resources
     ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);
     i.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
     i.setLayoutParams(new CoverFlow.LayoutParams(130, 130));
     i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE); 

     //Make sure we set anti-aliasing otherwise we get jaggies
     BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) i.getDrawable();
     drawable.setAntiAlias(true);
     return i;

  //return mImages[position];
 }
   /** Returns the size (0.0f to 1.0f) of the views 
  * depending on the 'offset' to the center. */ 
  public float getScale(boolean focused, int offset) { 
    /* Formula: 1 / (2 ^ offset) */ 
      return Math.max(0, 1.0f / (float)Math.pow(2, Math.abs(offset))); 
   } 

 }
 }
```

My main.xml (this is what ive tries to link but with no luck)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>




<cover.flow.test.CoverFlow
    android:id="@+id/coverflow"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Comment: I dont have a logcat error. It either doesnt show when i try to link it or crashes

Comment: If it crashes, there should be an exception shown in the log (logcat).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To link with the view you need something like

setContentView(R.layout.main);

and remove the code creating the CoverFlow instance (instead get it with findViewById, etc.)

Comment: You have to post the code which makes the error instead the working one (or additionally). And if the application crashes you are very probably getting an error message in logcat.